# Alternative to Google Adsense

Tags: google

I'm starting a small site with some online tools. Tried to include Google Adsense but I initially got rejected because the site was still on construction.

Yet I've seen in the forums that they are rejecting many small sites or sites that has already other sites doing the same thing, because they don't consider them "of value".
I will be finishing my site these days and I really didn't want to start without some kind of ads in it.

If I get rejected again, can you recommend some alternative to Google AdSense ? Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Here are a few to look at

[Adversal](https://www.adversal.com/)

[Sovrn](https://www.viglink.com/)

[Skimlinks](https://skimlinks.com/)

[Monumetric](https://www.monumetric.com/)

[InfoLinks](https://www.infolinks.com/)

[ylliX](https://yllix.com/en/)

[Evadav](https://evadav.com/)

[PopCash](https://popcash.net/)

[PopAds](https://www.popads.net/)

[RevContent](http://www.revcontent.com/)

[Adsterra](https://adsterra.com/)

[SHE Media](https://www.shemedia.com/)

[AdRecover](https://kinsta.com/blog/ad-blockers/)

[MadAds](http://www.madadsmedia.com/)

[Bidvertiser](https://www.bidvertiser.com/)

[Adbuff](https://adbuff.com/)

[BuySellAds](https://www.buysellads.com/)

[AdClickMedia](https://adclickmedia.com/)

Comment: Any advice or experience to share?

Comment: This site is not about posting a list of Google search results. It is about giving someone a recommendation based on own experience.